# Is there a pre-defined library of conversations for chatscript?

Tags: chatbot, chatscript

I'm building a bot with chatscript and there is a lot to give it as far as what it can say and what it will react to. I've googled a lot but there doesn't seem to be much documentation or sources for chatscript. Does anyone know of a library of predefined common conversations to use as a starting point? I know the demo comes with one talking about childhood, but that doesn't seem like it'd be a common conversation with a bot.

Answer (score 3):

While the narrative given is quite simple, the quibble code that comes with CS is quite extensive. Also, most of the example program actually reside in  `yourchatscriptdir/RAWDATA/QUIBBLES`

This is exactly what you seem to be after: thousands of lines of fast answers for back and forth.

To include it into your build, 
- first add `RAWDATA/QUIBBLE/` to your build file (typically `file1.txt` or `botname.txt`)
- include the following code somewhere near the end of your `simple_control.top` file

```
if (%response == 0) {
 ^respond(~QUIBBLE_ALL)
}
```

Since the `~QUIBBLE_ALL` topic will be included when you build your bot, any input that did not generate an output up to that point will respond from the quibble code.

Also, refer to the doc https://github.com/bwilcox-1234/ChatScript/tree/master/WIKI